# Custom UICollectionView cells layoutsubview is incorrect after scrolling

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` that contains a BOOL value called isOnSale. I set this value in `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. A label is added to the cell if the `isOnSale` is true. This works perfectly, however if I scroll down and then scroll back up the labels have swapped to the cell next in the index. I scroll up, and back down, they are back to there original places. I am guessing it is a layout problem but I have spent the last hour or so trying to spot the bug, while implementing other examples here.

Here is my `UICollectionViewCell`

```
@implementation SaleCollectionViewCell


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
       self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        self.sale = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.bgImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iron1"];

        [self.contentView insertSubview:self.bgImageView atIndex:0];

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews{

    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.isOnSale) {
        self.sale.frame =CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height - 41, 140, 41);
        self.sale.text = @"On Sale";
        self.sale.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.sale.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
        self.sale.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.sale.backgroundColor= [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        self.sale.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kAppFont size:17.0];
        [self.contentView insertSubview:self.sale atIndex:2];

        self.bgImageView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, self.bounds.size.height - self.sale.bounds.size.height);

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Is not on sale");
        self.bgImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);


    }

}
@end
```

If the item is on sale then `layoutSubViews` updates the view and adds the `Sale` label to the cell.

Here is my `UICollectionView` `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    SaleCollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.clipsToBounds = YES;

    SaleImage * saleImage = [self.saleObjs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.bgImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:saleImage.imageName];
    if (saleImage.isOnSale) {
        cell.isOnSale = YES;
    }
    else{
        cell.isOnSale=NO;
    }

    return cell;

}
```

The problem is that the Sale label is moving when the cells leave the screen. Its strange, because the `self.bgImageView` shows the correct content.

If anything is unclear please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove your label from the superview in either `layoutSubviews`'s `else` branch or in `-prepareForResuse` method

Comment: That did not fix it unfortunately :(

Comment: I had to add `[self setNeedsLayout]`